# Fetch file as byte array in spring integration

Tags: spring, sftp, spring-integration

I'm new to spring integration. I need to fetch some file via sftp and immediately start some processing on the content of that file. There is  `SFTP Inbound Channel Adapter` that partially satisfy me. But it saves(as documentation says) fetched file in local directory. I have no possibility to save it on local machine, but just want to start processing the content of that file, so it will be good for me to retrieve remote file as byte array or as `InputStream`. How can I achieve this with spring integration?

Also I want to configure my system to periodically fetch that file. I know that I can configure spring bean with `@Scheduled` annotation on some method and start processing from that method. But, maybe, spring integration has more elegant solution for such case?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration 3.0.1 has a new `RemoteFileTemplate` that you can use to programmatically receive a file as a stream. See the [Javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/RemoteFileTemplate.html#get%28org.springframework.integration.Message,org.springframework.integration.file.remote.InputStreamCallback%29).